# Where can I find a good online Python course?

Tags: python

Does anyone know where I can find a quality online Python course that would be suitable for someone with a math/engineering background, but not in software?

Comment: Quite related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111857/what-did-you-use-to-teach-yourself-python

Comment: Take a look at here: https://coorsy.com/topics/python

Answer (score 6):

One Source would be even Better It is [Intro to CS101 "Building a Search Engine"](http://www.udacity.com/overview/Course/cs101/CourseRev/apr2012)

here you can learn Python and Develop a web crawler with the google's page rank algorithm capabilities.

Answer (score 5):

This course from MIT Open course ware - [A gentle introduction to programming using Python](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-189-a-gentle-introduction-to-programming-using-python-january-iap-2008/)

This one has video lectures too - [Introduction to Computer Science and Programming](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-fall-2008/video-lectures/)

Though they are good introductions to programming, reading a good book/tutorial must be enough to get you up to speed in Python.

Comment: Also Coursera offer a lot of interesting Python courses.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend just using the [python tutorial](http://docs.python.org/py3k/tutorial/), it's one of the more documented programming languages in terms of it's tutorial out there. The best way to learn to program is to start writing a program that you want, and the tutorial will help you do so.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Google's online Python class](http://code.google.com/edu/languages/google-python-class/) too.

Answer (score 0):

I have just started learning Python too and I have found the e-book [Think Python](http://greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkpython.html) very useful.

Answer (score 0):

[Learn Python The Hard Way](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/) is specifically made for non-programmers.

Comment: link is broken; please remove "index"